# Reactjs - function called in render() is called multiple times when clicking a Tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I started my first Reactjs project yesterday and I've ran into an issue.

The application uses React Bootstrap - mainly just the "Tab" and "Tabs" componenets right now, as well as jQuery datatables.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Have a couple of tabs on my UI
2. Do not load both tabs at once, only load a tab when its clicked. I've done this by adding mountOnEnter={true} in the Tabs div
3. When a tab is first loaded, initialise a datatabes object. If it's not created, simply call ajax.reload()

So I figured out I could set a state variable to true when a tab has been clicked, then pass this state variable to the Datatable component as a property. Then the Datatable component can simply check the state and either create a datatable or just do another ajax call to refresh the data.

### TabsExample component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs'
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab'
import {Datatable} from '../datatable/Datatable'
import './TabsExample.css'

export class TabsExample extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            'key': 'tab1',
            'hasInitialised': false
        }
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }

    // Update the state when a tab is clicked
    handleSelect(selectedTab) {
        this.setState({key: selectedTab, hasInitialised: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="tabs-container">
                <Tabs defaultActiveKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} mountOnEnter={true}>
                    <Tab eventKey="tab1" title="Tab 1">
                        <Datatable initStatus={this.state.hasInitialised} tabName={this.state.key}>
                        </Datatable>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab eventKey="tab2" title="Tab 2">
                        <Datatable initStatus={this.state.hasInitialised} tabName={this.state.key}>
                        </Datatable>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### Datatable component

Note: I then found out that you can use componentDidMount() - which I believe fires when the component is first mounted and then never again, so it makes sense to put the initialisation code in here.
Another note: I haven't implemented the ajax call yet, so for now I'm just printing out the properties to see if "initStatus" has been set to true.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'
import './Datatable.css'

const $ = require('jquery')
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net-bs4')

export class Datatable extends Component {

    someFunc() {
        // -----------------------------------------------------------
        // this gets called 4 times every time a tab is clicked???
        // -----------------------------------------------------------
        console.log(this.props);

        // I want to do something like this
        // if (this.props.initStatus)
            // ajax.reload()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.$el = $(this.el)

            this.$el.DataTable(
                {
                    lengthMenu: [ 15, 50, 75 ],
                    columns: [
                        { title: "Name" },
                        { title: "Position" },
                        { title: "Office" },
                        { title: "Extn." },
                        { title: "Start date" },
                        { title: "Salary" }
                    ]
                }
            )
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.$el.DataTable.destroy(true)
    }

    render() {
        this.someFunc()
        return <div>
            <div class="table-container">
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" ref={el => this.el = el}>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

So while this works and I can see that the value is "true" as I expect, I don't understand why the function gets called 4 times. Obviously I don't want this as when I implement the ajax call it will do 4 requests.

### Output when clicking from Tab 1 to Tab 2

```
{initStatus: true, tabName: "tab2"}
{initStatus: true, tabName: "tab2"}
{initStatus: true, tabName: "tab2"}
{initStatus: true, tabName: "tab2"}
```

Tab 2 to Tab  produces the same output

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: So I think it's worth answering your question because it will help you learn React better. But it's also totally worth mentioning that you're making it 1000x harder on yourself by using jQuery datatables. There are many great tables for react https://react-table.js.org in particular.